# How do I interpret this backtracking code?

Tags: recursive-backtracking

I'm having a hard time understanding backtracking code. In particular, I know we always explore and backtrack when we don't find a solution, but I don't understand the logic behind the `path.pop()` line.

I know we must pop elements after exploration, but how does this pop off the right element?

Before that, we may recurse all the way down to the children nodes

`# If current vertex is not destination 
            #Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
            for i in self.graph[u]: 
                if visited[i]==False: 
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path)`

 so how do we guarantee `path.pop()` removes `u` and not some other node? It makes sense when I draw out a recursion tree but is there an easier way to understand this?

```
   '''A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'. 
    visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path. 
    path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current 
    index in path[]'''
    def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path): 

        # Mark the current node as visited and store in path 
        visited[u]= True
        path.append(u) 

        # If current vertex is same as destination, then print 
        # current path[] 
        if u ==d: 
            print path 
        else: 
            # If current vertex is not destination 
            #Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
            for i in self.graph[u]: 
                if visited[i]==False: 
                    self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path) 

        # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited 
        path.pop() 
        visited[u]= False


    # Prints all paths from 's' to 'd' 
    def printAllPaths(self,s, d): 

        # Mark all the vertices as not visited 
        visited =[False]*(self.V) 

        # Create an array to store paths 
        path = [] 

        # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths 
        self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d,visited, path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printAllPathsUtil` receives a pointer to your current `path` object with every call. New calls to `printAllPathsUtil` are always made on the basis that the path so far is unexplored and valid. If the recursive function finds, that it has reached the destination `d`, then it prints out the complete current path and takes a step back, i.e. the last vertice of your path is cut off and the algorithm tries to find an alternative path to `d` (which then must be a "detour" with more than 1 vertices, assuming your graph has no duplicate vertices). Otherwise, `d` is not reached yet and you continue exploring all vertices going out of `u`, that are not in `path` already (so you don't go back where you came from). This goes on until all possible paths going out of your initial `s` have been tested.

Throughout that process, `path` was *only extended* whenever more recursion was possible and *trimmed* in order to *backtrack* to earlier states. In other words, you perform a [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) through your graph, branching after every vertice (even if there's only 1). The algorithm always first exhausts all possible paths, before it backtracks, thus `append`-ing and `pop`-ing are correct methods to keep track of your progress.